# Angular Elements produces HTML all on one line

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-elements

This is extremely annoying. As many of you probably know, [there is a "bug"](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) with browsers, that treat inline-block elements kind of weird. If you place two inline-block elements next to each other, they will have an invisible margin, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8o50engu/

However, if they were on the same line, the weird space would disappear: http://jsfiddle.net/8o50engu/1/

If I make an Angular Elements application (see the `app.module.ts` file in the StackBlitz link below), my HTML from my component is all on one line. This means that the HTML I write is different from the output. You can see an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fowosb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

As you can see, my elements are clearly on separate lines:

```
<div>
  <span>
    span#1
  </span>
  <span>
    span#2
  </span>
</div>
```

However, the output is on one line:

[image]

This works fine in a regular Angular application (not Angular Elements), so clearly it's a problem with Angular Elements.

Is there a way to disable this in Angular Elements? It fixes the problem I explained in the beginning, but it's not what I want. I want my HTML to output as I wrote it.

Comment: Sometimes you have to work around browser quirks. Clearly, if you put span in each line, you want to have some margin between them applied by a browser. In that case if Angular Elements puts them in one line and because of that you don't see the margin, simply apply `display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px` to `span`element and move on to other tasks.

Comment: @codeepic That does not fix this problem. I could easily style my way out of this, but it's annoying that my HTML is not the same as the HTML in my browser.

Comment: You are using @Stackblitz which is an a VM for online code editing - they may be using some HTML parser that removes spaces between inline elements - putting `span` tags in one line. You wouldn't have this problem if you were using  a code editor. Just accept it, cause you don't have control over how Stackblitz generates html. Or hit the creators on Twitter https://twitter.com/stackblitz?lang=en or Discord https://discordapp.com/invite/stackblitz channel. It's 2 guys and they are very approachable.

Comment: Someone who thinks you're making a big issue out of smth small. Here, I upvoted it, so you're back to 0.

Comment: @codeepic I don't think you understand the problem. I'm using Stackblitz to show off the problem and so that people can reply with an answer. Just like someone would use JSFiddle. I experience the exact same issue on my local PC. And thank you for the upvote.

Comment: Quote: If I make an Angular Elements application (see the app.module.ts file in the StackBlitz link below), my HTML from my component is all on one line. EndQuote. Ok, I see what you mean. In that case `Angular Elements` applies the logic to put component html code in 1 line. Nothing you can do about it, so apply the CSS to give `spans` proper spacing and be done with it. It's not a bug, it's a design decision made by Angular team for minifying html generated by `Angular Elements`. They won't make an exception. Work around it. Embrace the pain of front-end & enjoy it.

Comment: @codeepic Some frameworks have different flags you can set, if you want x to happen instead of y. If their decision was to make your code execute differently than how you wrote it, their decision is definitely stupid. There should be a way to enable it, so our code and our output is the same (as expected). The basics of HTML is completely ignored here.

Comment: Fair point, find out if you can configure the html output. Raise it with `Angular Elements` team if not, and in a mean time just apply the damn CSS, cause you're gonna be growing old by the time they take your suggestion into consideration, if it wasn't raised by at least few other people. And god knows, how long until they add this option to configuration.

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted this question. One suggestion however: could you remove the sentence "This works fine in a regular Angular application..."? The question would be clearer without it, IMHO.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Because it does work fine in a regular Angular application. If I remove the Angular Elements aspect of it, it will output HTML as I wrote it. Thanks for the answer that actually works, however :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rendering behavior is controlled by the [preserveWhitespaces](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preservewhitespaces) Component decorator option. The white spaces will be preserved in the HTML output if you set the option to `true`, as shown below and as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtargy). By default, `preservedWhitespaces` is `false`.

```
@Component({
  ...
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a way to disable that. Thanks a lot!